# How to pass a binary buffer via python ctypes to a c function

Tags: python, wrapper, ctypes

I'd like to wrap the following c function bar() in python 2.x and invoke 
it via the ctypes module, both on Linux and Windows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef FOO_DLL
#define FOO_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define FOO_API extern
#endif

FOO_API unsigned int bar(const void* data, unsigned int len) 
{
   printf("%p (%d bytes)\n", data, len);
   return len;
}
```

To compile the shared library I use scons:

```
import sys

env = Environment()
if sys.platform == 'win32':
  env.Append(CFLAGS=['-DFOO_DLL'])

env.SharedLibrary('foo', ['foo.c'])
```

Finally I load the respective shared lib and invoke the function:

```
import sys
import struct
from ctypes import *

if sys.platform == 'win32':
  libfoo = windll.LoadLibrary('foo')
else:
  libfoo = cdll.LoadLibrary('./libfoo.so')

data = struct.pack('BBB', 0, 1, 2)
libfoo.bar(data, len(data))
```

To my surprise this seems to work flawlessly under Linux, but on Windows the
code throws an error that makes me suspects that this isn't the proper
way to do things:

```
$ python foo.py
00B520C4 (3 bytes)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 11, in <module>
    libfoo.bar(data, len(data))
ValueError: Procedure probably called with too many arguments (8 bytes in excess)
```

What would be the right approach?

On Linux (Ubuntu 10.10 64bit) I'm using Python 2.6.6, gcc 4.4.5 and on Windows (XP 32bit, in a VirtualBox) Python 2.7.1 and VS2010 Express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Windows and Linux should use `cdll` which results in the C calling convention. The Python code at present calls your Windows DLL using `stdcall` but it's really a `cdecl` function. The difference between `cdll` and `windll` is just the calling convention used.

That error message is a textbook calling convention mismatch error, for what it's worth.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I somehow assumed that on windows I should use windll. Stupid me. Using "libfoo = cdll.LoadLibrary('foo')" for the win32 part works flawlessly.